# How to define pointer for a custom input iterator

Tags: c++, pointers, iterator

I am writing a custom input iterator that adapts an underlying sequence and yields transformed values (I know about [`boost::transform_iterator`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/iterator/doc/transform_iterator.html), but this is special).

I am unsure how to define `pointer`-type for this iterator. Since the iterator generates values on the fly, `reference` is defined as an alias for `value_type` (which is allowed for input iterators, `reference` must merely be convertible to `value_type`). My intuition is that it would still just be `value_type *`, and I can't really think of anything else that would make sense.

However, I haven't found any information about the context in which `pointer` is expected to be used, and hence don't know what requirements are placed on it, and the documentation of `boost::transform_iterator` (which usually offers useful advice) is silent on this issue.

So my question is, is it generally safe to just define `pointer` as `value_type *`? If not, what are the alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing I can find in the standard that calls out what they should refers to comes from [iterator.traits]

> [...]In addition, the types
>
> ```
> iterator_traits<Iterator>::reference
> iterator_traits<Iterator>::pointer
> ```
>
> shall be defined as the iterator’s reference and pointer types, that is, for an iterator object `a`, the same type as the type of `*a` and `a->`, respectively.